# Backbone with complex REST interface

Tags: backbone.js

The rest interface I'm currently working has something like this,

Returns a collection

```
POST /base/Holiday/getHolidaySetup/
FORM_DATA: client_id:1
```

Even worse..

```
POST /base/Holiday/setAddHoliday/
FORM_DATA: client_id:1
... other form data..
```

Clearly in a newer scheme, it'd look something like

```
/base/Holiday/client/
POST to create a new holiday.
/base/Holiday/client/
GET To retrieve holidays
```

But, that's just not what we're working with..

So how do I set Backbone up for such a scheme.

Comment: First one is a `model.fetch`, second one a `model.save` ?

Comment: First is a `collection.fetch`, second one is a `model.save`

Comment: You'll have to override the `sync` method for your objects

Answer (score 0):

You can completely change how your models and collections handle their persistence by overriding their respective `sync` methods.

For example, to fetch a collection

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "client_id"
});

var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    url: "/base/Holiday/getHolidaySetup/",

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var params = {
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({client_id: 1}),
            url: _.result(this, 'url'),
            processData: false
        };

        var xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
        model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L9v5rkz/5/

or to save a model

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "client_id",
    url: '/base/Holiday/setAddHoliday/',

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};

        var params = {
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false
        };

        if ((method === 'create') || (method === 'update')) {
            params.url = _.result(this, 'url');
            params.data = JSON.stringify(this.toJSON(options));
        } else {
            // handle read and delete operations
        }

        var xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
        model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L9v5rkz/2/